# increasing sensor sampling rate hooked via I2C

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, sensors, gyroscope, i2c

I am using a Raspberry Pi to talk to MPU6050 sensor with I2C.
Say, I've got a code which reads sensor data in loop. To calculate loop speed I do so:

## pseudocode

```
for (;;) {
    I2CInterface.getSensorData(device address, register address, data);
    oldTime = currentTime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &currentTime);
    dt = currentTime - oldTime;
    some easy calculations envolving dt like multiplying
    fprintf(f, "%7d \n", dt);
}
```

dt I get is around 0.0017-0.0018 seconds which is about 580-550 Hz which is not enough for me.

If I run same code without I2CInterface.getSensorData, multiplication and fprintf lines, I get around 50MHz.
Where does frequency go in such massive amount? Much time is needed to read Register through I2C? Time is gone to make a calculation part? fprintf causes delay?

Comment: Please, check if MPU6050 allows for faster polling. Looks like the device is either miss configured or it can not sample faster than that.

Comment: Given that your I2C bus is probably running at 100**KHz** which is around 12,000 bytes per second, there is no way you are getting 50MHz out of your loop.

Comment: I beleive sample rate of  MPU6050 have nothing to do with loop frequency.
Sample rate of device is how fast it can refresh it's own value of register. Problem is how fast can I read this values.

Comment: As I said, I'm getting 50MHz loop with no calculations or I2C being used. Just looped dt calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I2C is generally slow - clock rate starts from 100kHz and this device can be clocked at 400kHz max. At 100kHz throughput is comparable to piddly RS232. Exchanging 20 bytes is sufficient to throttle you down to 600Hz.

Check how much data is exchanged between your board and `MPU6050` and try to estimate how fast you can go on a given clock rate. Verify your I2C clock rate setting.

Comment: Looks like you are exactly correct. I'm reading 14 bytes with I2C each time and looks like that's why it's looking throttled. Thanks.

Comment: Rading 14 bytes means that you have to first address the device, set register address, etc. As a result you probably exchange more than 14 bytes in total. You'll get additional delays from your OS. If it is not RTOS or bare-metal application, forget about low latency.